# How to reset polymer file-input element, to be able to upload the same file again consecutively?

Tags: file-upload, polymer, web-component

We have a file-input element, that is used to upload JSON files which in turn feed a jade template. However, if the user tries to upload the same file (with changes) again, the on-change event does not get triggered.
We have tried wrapping the file-input inside an HTML form and resetting the form for each upload, but that does not fix the problem.
This is a stripped down version of the HTML:

```
<polymer-element name="x-application">
  <template>
    <div class='body-wrap' vertical layout flex>
      <div class='main-nav'>
        <file-input id="file" on-change="{{changeHandler}}">
          <div>Open File</div>
        </file-input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

The handler(written in coffee-script) looks like:

```
changeHandler: (e) ->
    reader = new FileReader()
    file = @$.file.files[0]
    reader.onload = (e) =>
         #do some stuff on load      
    reader.readAsText(file)
```

We would like to be able to upload the same file with changes multiple times. Also, the application is expected to work reliably only on Chrome 38+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handler you might want to `reset` `file-input`:

```
Polymer('x-application', {
  changeHandler: function(e) {
    this.$.file.reset();
    alert('Bingo!');
  }
});
```

or, caffeinated:

```
changeHandler: (e) ->
  @$.file.reset()
  ...
```

Live preview (does not include CSS, try to select a file twice): http://plnkr.co/edit/GDPGNZuIQHDmf8AOkgE4?p=preview